# SQL Strange error Default Value

Tags: mysql, null

I have an app that require a database.
I set the database row of "pskinsurl" to `none`, and I get this error:

```
[2017-11-02 18:06:58.514] [ERROR] [default] - Strange error
[2017-11-02 18:06:58.515] [ERROR] [default] - { Error: ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD:                 Field 'pskinsurl' doesn't have a default value
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protoc                ol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences                /Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Proto                col.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:1                2)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:                39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103                :28)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.                js:145:48)
    at Connection.query (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:208:2                5)
    at Query._callback (/var/www/Bot/cf.js:3293:26)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequence                s/Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/proto                col/sequences/Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Q                uery.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Proto                col.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:76:1                2)
    at Protocol.write (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:                39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/www/Bot/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:103                :28)
  code: 'ER_NO_DEFAULT_FOR_FIELD',
  errno: 1364,
  sqlMessage: 'Field \'pskinsurl\' doesn\'t have a default value',
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO games SET expire = 1509662218, cassetids = \'12530890030\',                 csteamid = \'76561198114317007\', cname = \'KnottyCord\', cavatar = \'https://st                eamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/1d/1d3f34eee812968fd5                548f36ee281265373ddf91_full.jpg\', cskinsurl = \'-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWw                KGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fRPasw8rsVFx5KAVo5PSkKV4xhfG                fKTgVvIXlxNPSwaOmMLiGwzgJvJMniO-Zoo_z2wXg-EVvfSmtc78HsNoy\', cskinsnames = \'Gam                ma 2 Case\', cskinsprices = \'0.03\', cskins = 1, ctp = 0.03, cpick = \'t\', tcr                eated = 1509660418.494, hash = \'adb9037cfd700a24544d4d774189a223\', bot = \'bot                1\'' }
```

I get this error with the value "As defined 0"
But if I set it to `NULL` I get this error in the Google Dev `Console`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
    at onMessage (app.js?v1509661538:353)
    at r.<anonymous> (app.js?v1509661538:1280)
    at r.emit (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:1)
    at r.onevent (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:2)
    at r.onpacket (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:2)
    at r.<anonymous> (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:2)
    at r.emit (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:1)
    at r.ondecoded (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:1)
    at s.<anonymous> (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:2)
    at s.r.emit (socket.io-1.4.5.js:sourcemap:1)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about and which programming language is that?

Comment: I thinks it's java or node js and the database is managed with phpmyadmin

Comment: Do you have any idea? @marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert, you need to specify a value for at least all fields that don’t have a default value are are not set to allow null.

You either need to specify a value for those fields or change the field to allow null or have a default value.

Comment: Well the problem is that other people just put the value to none and it work's for them, and we have the same file. Could it be a permission problem?

Comment: Do you have any idea?